# Undercut saw or oscillating saw for cutting trim for flooring?

Tags: flooring

I have heard conflicting things about whether an undercut saw or an oscillating saw should be used to cut casings and baseboard trim when installing flooring.

In a corner, it would seem an oscillating saw would have to be used, but what is the rule in general?

I ask because I had a floor installer show up and my finish carpenters warned me that if the guy showed up with an oscillating saw I should stop him because they said it would not make a clean cut. This happened and when I questioned why he was not using an undercut saw, the installer left in a huff.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't ask very politely. You'd be better off revising to not ask for a "rule". Those don't usually exist.

Comment: It really depends on how much cutting is to be done. For trim around a door frame, a steady hand with an oscillating saw with the blade on top of a scrap piece of flooring does a perfect job. For baseboards, the "best" way is usually to remove and reinstall them. If you have finish carpenters on site, that implies you're having the finish work done now, too. If that's the case, the right answer is to not install the baseboard until the flooring is in, then there won't be need for long rip cuts on them.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a lot of casing to raise, rent an undercut saw. They're *much* faster than oscillating saws (though the time benefit depends on how far you have to drive to rent).

If you're buying a new tool to *own*, an oscillating saw is probably more useful and will get the job done.

Quality of cuts in either case depend on technique and skill. You can make a real mess if you let the undercut saw blade bind or approach from the wrong angle. It'll tear out the entire face of the piece. You can end up with a wiggly line or scarring using an oscillating saw if you don't keep the blade down tight against a scrap flooring shim while you cut.

Comment: The quality of the cut can also depend on the quality of the blade and whether it's a rip or crosscut blade. Cutting baseboard is a rip cut, while cutting the bottom of door trim is a crosscut. If there are issues, switching blades could make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

"What is the rule?" I really don't think there is a rule. I think it's a matter of opinion. I rented an undercut saw when I tiled my hallway, lots of door jambs, and it worked great. When i did the bedrooms, few door jambs, I used my oscillating saw and supported it with a block of wood. It worked just as well for all practical purposes. You mentioned cutting baseboard trim, If cutting a good length of it to put flooring under it, then an undercut saw would be my choice.

Did the installer come back with an undercut saw?

Answer (score 0):

If you are that concerned, you will be using a tiny jigsaw to do the *coping* on the baseboards after you cut them.  Making sure you can cut the original chop-to-length at an accurate angle and accurate cut is sufficient:  I used an inexpensive miter saw  ("chop saw") but set up zero-clearance fence and backing board, and added a thick stabilizer plate against the blade, and practiced to make sure I could "chop" cleanly (I could repeatedly cut to 2/1000 inch precision).  There is some side-to-side slop in the chopping mechanism so you have to pull it carefully.

When more precision was needed, I used a hand saw miter saw that's like a hacksaw-style blade, on pistons so it can move up and down but stay on the set angle.

When doing the hardwood floors, I used a quality Japanese-style "pull" saw with a very fine blade, to cut the pieces around closets and other irregular shapes.  But that's not all there is to it!  I found that the front and back wall of the house are not exactly parallel!  So, where the two rooms met in the entryway, I carefully tapered several rows of planks (and recut the tongue or groove) to adjust the courses to the correct angle, spread over 5 rows.

Worst of all, the floor isn't perfectly flat, so parallel lines with converge or diverge anyway, even if fit perfectly.

Bottom line:  determine the precision and care you need, and make sure you can achieve that with whatever tools you choose.  (by "care" I mean related issues like chipping or tear-out of the face veneer)